# How to redirect the output of csh script that runs in background

Tags: shell, unix, csh

I'm running multiple csh scripts in parallel (each script takes 2 arguments) that does a lots of funny stuff in the background (details are not important to my problem). So far I'm running them as:

```
my_script arg1 arg2 &
my_script arg3 arg4 & 
...
```

This works just fine but I would like that each run of the script to redirect it's standard output into a log file. If I do the following command works well:

```
my_script arg1 arg2 >! somefile.log
```

The problem is that I need to run at least 5 of these scripts in parallel (background each of them). When I try the following sequence, the jobs are dispatched but is reported as "Suspended (tty output)" and the log file is not updating:

```
my_script arg1 arg2 >! somefile.log &
my_script arg3 arg4 >! somefile1.log &
my_script arg5 arg6 >! somefile2.log &
....
```

Any ideas to this issue. Oh...also I forgot to mention that I need to use CSH unfortunatelly I can't switch to bash or anything else.

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried running with `nohup` and standard output redirection ">&" ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried both options still the same result. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
nohup my_script arg1 arg2 < /dev/null >! somefile.log &
```

You can also try

```
stty -tostop
```

to manage the terminal mode

Comment: @Birbal : Which trick (or both) worked for you? Good luck to all.

Comment: The first option worked...I haven't try the second one